# How do I perform navigation using Link in React + Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-router, react-router-dom

```
const pages = ['home', 'menu', 'reservation'];

<Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' } }}>
  {pages.map((page) => (
    <Link component={Link} to='/'>Home</Link>
  ))}
</Box>
```

I tried watching one or two videos on how to use Routing in MUI, yet I was unable to find a solution to this. Tried implementing the examples from Routing Libraries from MUI and yet I was unable to get it. Is there a simpler way of getting it done? I have updated my routes and route in App.tsx.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly you are asking how to work with the `Link` component from `@mui/core` ***and*** the `Link` component from `react-router-dom`. You want to render MUI links using the RRD link as the actual rendered UI component.

Import *and alias* one of the `Link` components, typically the "inner" component. I suggest also updating the `pages` array to hold objects that have both the link target path and the label you would like to display for it. ***Don't forget to assign a React key to each mapped JSX element!***

Example:

```
import { Link } from '@mui/material';
import { Link as BaseLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const pages = [
  {
    label: "Home",
    path: "/",
  },
  {
    label: "Menu",
    path: "/menu",
  },
  {
    label: "Reservation",
    path: "/reservation",
  },
];

...

<Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: 'none', md: 'flex' } }}>
  {pages.map(({ label, path }) => (
    <Link key={path} component={BaseLink} to={path}>
      {label}
    </Link>
  ))}
</Box>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I understood that quite well!

Comment: @SohamShirke Ah, so I did have the correct understanding of the problem you had? And did this address/resolve your question/issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use react router dom package 6 .. 
here an example:

[Github example][1] 
it has many methods to navigate, like "link to" and useNavigate

```
import { Routes, Route, Outlet, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Layout() {
  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/dashboard">Dashboard</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/nothing-here">Nothing Here</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <hr />
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}
```